# Trigger airflow task on sensor timeout

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I currently have a `PythonSensor` which waits for files on an ftp server. Is it possible to have this sensor trigger a task on timeout? I am trying to create the following dag:

[airflow sensor diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7En4.png)

I have taken a look at `BranchPythonOperator` but it seems like I no longer get the benefits of rescheduling a task if it fails the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `trigger_rule="all_failed"` in your task?

> all_failed: All upstream tasks are in a failed or upstream_failed state

See http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html?highlight=all_failed#trigger-rules

And an example here http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html?highlight=all_failed#how-to-trigger-tasks-based-on-another-task-s-failure